# How would I go about installing two different versions of my app on the same test device?

Tags: ios, xcode

In a newer version of my app, I updated it to conform to a new protocol, but I want the old version of the app (whose xcodeproj I still have) to still be around on my device in case I need the old protocol.

To be clear this is not going out to customers, but I want a way to have two versions of my app on my phone. How would I go about doing this? My `Bundle identifier` is currently `me.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}` and I've heard things about changing that, but if I add a 2 before `rfc1034...` and run it it still installs over the app. What should I change it to if it's that?

Comment: You can add a new target (duplicate the old one) and change the Product Name in the build settings...

Comment: BTW - @DougSmith - It seems you never accept an answer to any of your questions. If someone posts an answer that solves your questions, please accept it. It helps you and it helps the person answering your question. Go back through your old questions and see if any answers deserve to be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, rmaddy. If you look through my questions, the vast majority have accepted answers, I've just lagged behind lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current bundle identifier is using the product name so you will need to change this to create this second version you want.

Go into the project target and choose build then find packaging. Change the product name here and you should find it works.

Comment: So right now it's `$(TARGET_NAME)` and I just change that to something different?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So why did adding 2 before the rfc part of the bundle identifier not work?

Comment: Because that's just a reference / a look up. It looks at what is set as your product name and sticks it in there :D

Answer (score 0):

Use two different bundle identifier.
In you case you can delete ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} in info-plist and give some hardcoded value which is different from your product name or you can change the product name in build setting of your target.